# how do I access the return value of a pointer accessing a function? (converting code to gcc)

Tags: class, pointers, gcc, vector

I want to retrieve the return value of a class function through a pointer.  In this case the return value is a vector (defined in class vec) and returned by GetA().  However, the code below produces an error.  Can you not assign the value of a function, using a pointer in this way?

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

#include "model.h"
#include "vector.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
//some code

model *thisModel;

thisModel = new model(name, outName, fileFormat);
vec a;
a = thisModel->GetA();   //this is line 264
```

The GetA function is defined in class model as:

```
vec model::GetA() {return a;}
```

I get the error: main.cpp:264: error: no matching function for call to ‘vec::vec(vec)’

Some background: I'm converting some code from compiling on Borland to gcc (it previously worked fine with Borland).  I've gotten rid of most of my errors but I still do not understand why the above code no longer works.  Also:

```
thisModel-> GetA();  //does not produce an error but does not return the vector I need
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that the vector apparently cannot be copied, so you cannot return a vec value. It would be a good idea to post the source of the GetA function here. Also, you would probably be better off switching over to the C++ Standard library std::vector class.

Comment: thanks.  although this is the GetA() function in it's entirety:          vec model::GetA() {return a;}                   I may just try to switch to the standard vector class as it was causing most of my problems to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

```
main.cpp:264: error: no matching function for call to ‘vec::vec(vec)’
```

This means that the class vec has no copy constructor.  If you can alter the code, add one:
`vec::vec(const vec& r) {/*initialize data*/}`
If the calling code is as you say, then I'd consider that a bug in gcc.  You can work around it by constructing vec a with one of the other constructors, or calling any member (like `.size()` ) before assigning it.
If your code is actually `vec a = /*stuff*/;` then that is a very common optimization, and I'm not sure which compiler is wrong in that case.